# Water Displacement in the Oceans As a result of Global Warming

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, ice

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but here goes.

If the north pole ice sheets melt, everyone agrees this would be a bad thing, however one of the reasons they state for this being a bad thing is the rise in sea level.

Given that the north pole is essentially a massive ice sheet floating on water, how can the melting of this ice raise the sea levels?

In my understanding the amount of water displaced by the ice, is equal to the amount of water that would be added to the ocean.

I tried an experiment where i marked the water level in a glass of water with ice, then waited for the ice to melt. the water level was identical.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate... not positive, though.

Comment: The problem is not sea ice, but ice bound up on land, e.g. [ice sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_sheet).

Comment: There is also the issue of increased fresh-water too, apparently it screws with th Gulf stream.